# Is it possible to distinguish a `const` variable from a non-`const` one and from a `const&` reference?

Tags: c++, reference, constants, immutability, sfinae

Suppose I wanted to make my own reference ("smart pointer") type which is guaranteed to always refer to *immutable* data, rather than merely immutably-viewed data. In other words, data which can't be mutated by *anyone*, as opposed to just not through that particular reference. This is not so easy, because C++ generally considers `const` things to be a subcase of mutable-access things, and `&` references implicitly convert to `const &`, likewise `*` to `const *`.

Let's call this type:

```
template<typename T>
class ImmRef { ... };
```

One straightforward thing I can do is to declare:

```
template<typename T>
struct Imm
{
    const T value;
};
```

and then only allow creating `ImmRef`s out of `Imm`s, or other `ImmRef`s. Here the variable itself is declared `const`, so it's not possible to make any mutable references to it, and it is in fact truly immutable. (Unless it internally uses `mutable`, but since there's nothing we can do about that, let's ignore it.)

That works, but for greater flexibility, wider applicability, and compatibility with other code which doesn't know about our `Imm` type, it would be much better if we could create `ImmRef`s to *any* `const`-declared variable. But it's not clear whether C++ makes it possible to distinguish "a variable that is declared `const`" from "a `const` reference to a variable", or even from "a variable that is not declared `const`".

In other words, this should work:

```
const int myConstNumber = 666;
ImmRef<int> myImmRef = immRef(myConstNumber);
```

But this should not:

```
int myNumber = 666;
ImmRef<int> myImmRef = immRef(myNumber);
```

And this should not:

```
const int& myConstRef = myNumber;
ImmRef<int> myImmRef = immRef(myConstRef);
```

Is there any dark template magic which lets me do this?

Comment: No, there isn't. BTW: This might be of interest, though at a tangent: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4150.pdf

Comment: Your system could always be fooled if you give it the value of `template <typename T> const T & f(const T & x) { return x; }`. You can't generally distinguish between values of id-expressions and other values.

Comment: You can distinguish between the first two, but the first and the third are impossible to distinguish.

Comment: @KerrekSB The only thing I can think of is a macro with `decltype`.

Comment: @T.C. Macro plus `decltype` actually seems like a reasonable solution (not airtight, but nothing in C++ is), thanks. If you submit it as an answer I'll accept it, if you want points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to tell that a reference refers to a real `const` object. And there's no way for a function to tell whether its argument names an object or a reference.

`decltype` will tell you specifically that a name belongs to a `const` object (not a reference), but the name must be in scope. This usage can't be encapsulated in a template.

A macro will do the job, if you really really want it:

```
#define MAKE_IMMREF( NAME ) ImmRef< decltype( NAME ) >{ NAME }

template<typename T>
struct ImmRef {
    static_assert ( std::is_const< T >::value, "ImmRef requires a constant." );

    T & ref;
};
```

[Demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fbcbc33b2adbf9b)